# google sheets api : get cell value for every spreadsheet in a collection

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-api

I have a spreadsheet collection. 
Each spreadsheet has a value in A1. 
I need to get this value for every single spreadsheet and collect them somewhere. 
I can retrieve my list of spreadsheet with a google drive api request (list request) and get all the fields I want. I set some specific properties for every spreadsheet. 
Can I retrieve some file content in this files.list request ? 
Does anyone have an idea how to proceed ?
I know I could loop a bunch of requests but those are limited by a quota, so I won't use them for this task. 
Please let me know if you want more precision about my needs.

Comment: Although I'm not sure the total number of Spreadsheet you want to retrieve the value from the cell "A1", if you want to avoid the reduction of API quota, how about using Drive service and Spreadsheet service of Google Apps Script? By this, the script can be worked without reducing the API quota. If I misunderstood your goal and this was not the direction you want, I apologize.

Comment: Hi Tanaike. Thank you for this reply. I am developing a web app which is meant to be stand alone. So I think app script can't help me. You seems to know a lot about Google apis. Do you know something about developper meta data for sheets documents? I thought I could write out a ref to a cell and get it back from a request...

Comment: Sheets api offers reasonable amount of quota. Don't think you'll need more than that if you loop through. Apps script can help you. It can post data you need to your webapp. Apps script can also create a web app([tag:google-apps-script-web-application]), which can be used as a api to do what you want(that has different quotas though)

Comment: Thank you for replying. I deeply apologize my comment was not useful for your situation.